# Certificate checking with OCSP and root CA not trusted

Tags: certificates, ocsp

I have a root certificate authority, an sub CA and an server.

The root ca delivers a certificate for the sub CA.

The sub CA delivers a certificate for the server.

I want to check all the certification chain, from the server to the root CA with OCSP.

The command

```
openssl ocsp -issuer chain.pem -cert server.pem -CAfile root_ca.crt -text -url http://ipa-ca.sub.berettadomaine.fr/ca/ocsp
```

gives the result:

```
Response Verify Failure

140376105273232:error:27069070:OCSP routines:OCSP_basic_verify:root ca not trusted:ocsp_vfy.c:166:

server.pem: good
```

chain.pem contains all the certificates (root ca, sub ca and server).

server.pem:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 10 (0xa)
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: O=DTI, CN=SUB.BERETTADOMAINE.FR
        Validity
            Not Before: Dec 29 20:26:37 2019 GMT
            Not After : Dec 25 12:12:51 2021 GMT
        Subject: O=SUB.BERETTADOMAINE.FR, CN=server.berettadomaine.fr
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:be:c0:fe:39:1d:65:b0:d8:14:a7:dc:4c:3d:f0:
                    7d:9d:92:a1:b1:fd:20:be:30:33:e8:4a:8c:71:e4:
                    b9:b7:b9:a5:79:4d:6e:4b:14:63:02:d3:c8:17:55:
                    7b:7f:5c:b6:7d:de:e7:1f:bd:2a:c0:3a:6a:f8:c4:
                    7c:b1:43:d3:98:a3:77:27:90:e4:1b:3d:82:94:72:
                    bb:84:2e:d4:42:fe:e2:07:77:04:4b:05:e5:83:6d:
                    44:34:eb:69:2d:35:af:cf:f9:a9:86:e6:9a:ac:1a:
                    fe:6f:28:a8:4f:38:2e:d1:96:b8:74:07:97:39:bc:
                    a8:89:f7:3d:4f:96:1e:b9:4d:1b:f7:ab:3a:03:6d:
                    2a:0c:f1:4b:6b:b8:03:04:88:39:6c:10:30:07:83:
                    a5:dd:15:71:a1:cd:91:6d:6b:be:44:bd:1f:f9:be:
                    29:6e:a1:e8:c0:92:ac:a9:d6:14:a3:65:c0:46:29:
                    56:47:7e:20:57:3e:f8:da:a9:73:32:37:a9:67:7f:
                    a9:34:4b:5f:6b:24:a4:4b:3b:39:ad:af:c0:f2:9c:
                    ab:c6:ea:4c:60:dd:d4:c2:9f:98:52:1a:00:6d:02:
                    58:11:6f:c0:e5:40:17:b4:31:72:5e:66:24:06:1c:
                    cc:01:ca:7e:bc:fa:40:1c:1f:ec:7d:f4:54:a6:4b:
                    6b:a1
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:51:BF:5E:48:55:C7:01:CD:B7:F9:0B:9D:D5:64:93:C8:E8:A4:B3:B2

            Authority Information Access: 
                OCSP - URI:http://ipa-ca.sub.berettadomaine.fr/ca/ocsp

            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Non Repudiation, Key Encipherment, Data Encipherment
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
            X509v3 CRL Distribution Points: 

                Full Name:
                  URI:http://ipa-ca.sub.berettadomaine.fr/ipa/crl/MasterCRL.bin
                CRL Issuer:
                  DirName: O = ipaca, CN = Certificate Authority

            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                4D:63:91:0C:9C:41:F1:6C:39:2D:E5:4D:82:3D:77:82:A7:4B:E8:A6
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:server.berettadomaine.fr, othername:<unsupported>, othername:<unsupported>
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         0b:9c:e9:0c:38:a9:5f:f6:3f:1e:9b:36:d7:83:79:c1:bc:ec:
         89:a2:da:94:ee:5e:fc:b0:a2:76:27:58:80:de:59:77:41:07:
         67:2d:6e:7e:6b:06:21:3f:69:af:26:7b:30:8d:21:41:4e:f4:
         32:7d:9c:46:e4:d1:d4:0d:df:3c:12:4e:f9:08:eb:ae:ff:8d:
         37:cf:00:60:ab:88:cd:22:f0:5c:e1:1e:30:0d:1e:67:07:cb:
         7b:07:15:3d:0e:67:b3:9a:4e:46:95:ee:62:22:6e:7a:57:39:
         54:05:99:0c:fb:cd:3f:26:08:17:fc:8b:5b:5d:15:04:f8:5c:
         72:68:05:e9:80:55:f7:c4:a4:11:d5:a1:4d:58:48:0f:c2:fb:
         43:85:42:da:e6:47:05:39:10:d7:81:ac:c0:bb:d3:f9:60:14:
         56:e5:94:ae:38:d7:3f:4b:6d:34:78:e3:68:67:6d:22:87:89:
         b3:5e:1e:84:45:63:43:57:9b:4e:87:0f:c9:10:0c:d8:7b:d0:
         4b:76:41:2c:d9:e5:57:4e:ee:c9:a4:cf:f1:bd:e6:aa:38:2b:
         39:24:3e:34:47:c1:c3:be:c7:e7:16:91:34:44:9e:62:24:06:
         1e:d2:38:f6:c2:7f:84:62:39:c4:fc:69:81:40:8d:e1:bb:9b:
         c1:e0:e6:39
```

root_ca.crt:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 1 (0x1)
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: O=BERETTADOMAINE.FR, CN=Certificate Authority
        Validity
            Not Before: Dec 21 05:51:00 2019 GMT
            Not After : Dec 21 05:51:00 2039 GMT
        Subject: O=BERETTADOMAINE.FR, CN=Certificate Authority
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:cc:11:0a:63:99:49:7c:a5:c1:c7:94:ad:81:48:
                    39:64:f6:a8:f9:7e:e7:6f:c0:1a:fd:51:15:0b:d1:
                    5b:36:d5:d5:c0:81:a4:da:8c:98:38:da:38:89:b1:
                    c4:f6:fc:a4:a1:b8:a8:c1:07:e9:b3:3e:92:09:16:
                    d5:77:1b:4b:87:4d:3f:93:ef:57:84:be:6d:79:16:
                    e7:b7:8f:ab:94:3d:ba:aa:f8:b8:e2:74:5f:e7:c5:
                    74:4e:32:75:26:b3:aa:18:2a:87:ad:90:e5:fe:4f:
                    54:65:33:52:a2:4a:6b:e0:77:6f:36:ad:c8:52:a3:
                    85:e4:fb:bc:25:07:b5:1a:0c:23:2a:87:62:59:4e:
                    b2:1c:5a:20:04:b0:44:73:b6:a5:14:5d:83:e3:9c:
                    43:7d:16:e4:28:07:8e:c1:78:b7:de:b2:7d:43:6c:
                    46:b6:7d:0f:26:d6:83:00:3e:ca:6f:7b:75:08:e7:
                    3c:90:8b:42:4b:3a:68:e5:88:2f:36:0a:58:53:29:
                    63:a3:eb:49:4e:42:c2:74:d6:e3:31:53:20:60:c5:
                    4c:3b:81:48:d7:4a:f4:12:ad:9b:e5:8e:78:ea:1d:
                    84:14:50:63:19:6c:f3:37:b1:43:6a:d7:1a:c4:c6:
                    be:80:dc:19:df:14:8d:92:5a:4f:75:4e:b7:4a:19:
                    ce:4d
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:52:5F:DD:DA:9B:F1:C3:7F:1D:93:FA:64:18:93:87:0F:44:14:76:18

            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Non Repudiation, Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                52:5F:DD:DA:9B:F1:C3:7F:1D:93:FA:64:18:93:87:0F:44:14:76:18
            Authority Information Access: 
                OCSP - URI:http://ipa-ca.berettadomaine.fr/ca/ocsp

    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         16:ac:8c:04:12:be:d0:1d:f1:bc:f0:aa:6d:3d:6c:5e:06:2f:
         4f:ca:4e:a9:ab:88:25:58:69:c5:83:85:78:3e:4a:42:c2:17:
         2c:4b:3a:8b:1a:94:94:72:f6:1c:7e:8e:2c:d3:ad:db:27:64:
         56:b8:e6:85:92:b2:71:d0:2f:56:7f:ca:08:48:e0:64:31:8c:
         9a:04:47:c1:78:56:76:57:44:2e:ca:91:b4:9d:30:a8:73:5e:
         55:9a:12:08:ff:85:46:dd:74:fc:27:f2:92:34:24:27:06:c7:
         5a:24:a0:cf:ce:ce:22:0e:42:6c:3e:ca:11:fc:27:01:6e:dd:
         bc:d3:0c:46:da:c3:af:47:87:15:a2:fe:86:fe:53:5e:d2:3c:
         ad:c0:60:fc:c6:64:74:f7:d8:ee:16:75:cb:91:68:e0:02:2f:
         71:82:27:69:3e:3c:cc:3f:19:88:60:f8:dd:8c:6c:20:37:ef:
         52:f4:b2:78:57:7e:f7:6a:c3:6a:6f:7e:f1:a3:b9:0f:f3:89:
         f8:7e:2a:e3:b7:af:0e:b3:82:b6:84:b9:64:60:df:16:68:31:
         14:f3:da:36:8a:e5:e3:c9:b0:66:14:e4:34:e7:eb:eb:8a:98:
         6e:dc:fd:fb:f8:f9:2c:8d:26:6e:dd:4d:38:5a:d5:89:1b:cb:
         4d:d5:14:44
```

chain.pem is the concatenation of certificates below:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 10 (0xa)
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: O=DTI, CN=SUB.BERETTADOMAINE.FR
        Validity
            Not Before: Dec 29 20:26:37 2019 GMT
            Not After : Dec 25 12:12:51 2021 GMT
        Subject: O=SUB.BERETTADOMAINE.FR, CN=server.berettadomaine.fr
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:be:c0:fe:39:1d:65:b0:d8:14:a7:dc:4c:3d:f0:
                    7d:9d:92:a1:b1:fd:20:be:30:33:e8:4a:8c:71:e4:
                    b9:b7:b9:a5:79:4d:6e:4b:14:63:02:d3:c8:17:55:
                    7b:7f:5c:b6:7d:de:e7:1f:bd:2a:c0:3a:6a:f8:c4:
                    7c:b1:43:d3:98:a3:77:27:90:e4:1b:3d:82:94:72:
                    bb:84:2e:d4:42:fe:e2:07:77:04:4b:05:e5:83:6d:
                    44:34:eb:69:2d:35:af:cf:f9:a9:86:e6:9a:ac:1a:
                    fe:6f:28:a8:4f:38:2e:d1:96:b8:74:07:97:39:bc:
                    a8:89:f7:3d:4f:96:1e:b9:4d:1b:f7:ab:3a:03:6d:
                    2a:0c:f1:4b:6b:b8:03:04:88:39:6c:10:30:07:83:
                    a5:dd:15:71:a1:cd:91:6d:6b:be:44:bd:1f:f9:be:
                    29:6e:a1:e8:c0:92:ac:a9:d6:14:a3:65:c0:46:29:
                    56:47:7e:20:57:3e:f8:da:a9:73:32:37:a9:67:7f:
                    a9:34:4b:5f:6b:24:a4:4b:3b:39:ad:af:c0:f2:9c:
                    ab:c6:ea:4c:60:dd:d4:c2:9f:98:52:1a:00:6d:02:
                    58:11:6f:c0:e5:40:17:b4:31:72:5e:66:24:06:1c:
                    cc:01:ca:7e:bc:fa:40:1c:1f:ec:7d:f4:54:a6:4b:
                    6b:a1
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:51:BF:5E:48:55:C7:01:CD:B7:F9:0B:9D:D5:64:93:C8:E8:A4:B3:B2

            Authority Information Access: 
                OCSP - URI:http://ipa-ca.sub.berettadomaine.fr/ca/ocsp

            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Non Repudiation, Key Encipherment, Data Encipherment
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
            X509v3 CRL Distribution Points: 

                Full Name:
                  URI:http://ipa-ca.sub.berettadomaine.fr/ipa/crl/MasterCRL.bin
                CRL Issuer:
                  DirName: O = ipaca, CN = Certificate Authority

            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                4D:63:91:0C:9C:41:F1:6C:39:2D:E5:4D:82:3D:77:82:A7:4B:E8:A6
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:server.berettadomaine.fr, othername:<unsupported>, othername:<unsupported>
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         0b:9c:e9:0c:38:a9:5f:f6:3f:1e:9b:36:d7:83:79:c1:bc:ec:
         89:a2:da:94:ee:5e:fc:b0:a2:76:27:58:80:de:59:77:41:07:
         67:2d:6e:7e:6b:06:21:3f:69:af:26:7b:30:8d:21:41:4e:f4:
         32:7d:9c:46:e4:d1:d4:0d:df:3c:12:4e:f9:08:eb:ae:ff:8d:
         37:cf:00:60:ab:88:cd:22:f0:5c:e1:1e:30:0d:1e:67:07:cb:
         7b:07:15:3d:0e:67:b3:9a:4e:46:95:ee:62:22:6e:7a:57:39:
         54:05:99:0c:fb:cd:3f:26:08:17:fc:8b:5b:5d:15:04:f8:5c:
         72:68:05:e9:80:55:f7:c4:a4:11:d5:a1:4d:58:48:0f:c2:fb:
         43:85:42:da:e6:47:05:39:10:d7:81:ac:c0:bb:d3:f9:60:14:
         56:e5:94:ae:38:d7:3f:4b:6d:34:78:e3:68:67:6d:22:87:89:
         b3:5e:1e:84:45:63:43:57:9b:4e:87:0f:c9:10:0c:d8:7b:d0:
         4b:76:41:2c:d9:e5:57:4e:ee:c9:a4:cf:f1:bd:e6:aa:38:2b:
         39:24:3e:34:47:c1:c3:be:c7:e7:16:91:34:44:9e:62:24:06:
         1e:d2:38:f6:c2:7f:84:62:39:c4:fc:69:81:40:8d:e1:bb:9b:
         c1:e0:e6:39
```

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 10 (0xa)
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: O=DTI, CN=SUB.BERETTADOMAINE.FR
        Validity
            Not Before: Dec 29 20:26:37 2019 GMT
            Not After : Dec 25 12:12:51 2021 GMT
        Subject: O=SUB.BERETTADOMAINE.FR, CN=server.berettadomaine.fr
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:be:c0:fe:39:1d:65:b0:d8:14:a7:dc:4c:3d:f0:
                    7d:9d:92:a1:b1:fd:20:be:30:33:e8:4a:8c:71:e4:
                    b9:b7:b9:a5:79:4d:6e:4b:14:63:02:d3:c8:17:55:
                    7b:7f:5c:b6:7d:de:e7:1f:bd:2a:c0:3a:6a:f8:c4:
                    7c:b1:43:d3:98:a3:77:27:90:e4:1b:3d:82:94:72:
                    bb:84:2e:d4:42:fe:e2:07:77:04:4b:05:e5:83:6d:
                    44:34:eb:69:2d:35:af:cf:f9:a9:86:e6:9a:ac:1a:
                    fe:6f:28:a8:4f:38:2e:d1:96:b8:74:07:97:39:bc:
                    a8:89:f7:3d:4f:96:1e:b9:4d:1b:f7:ab:3a:03:6d:
                    2a:0c:f1:4b:6b:b8:03:04:88:39:6c:10:30:07:83:
                    a5:dd:15:71:a1:cd:91:6d:6b:be:44:bd:1f:f9:be:
                    29:6e:a1:e8:c0:92:ac:a9:d6:14:a3:65:c0:46:29:
                    56:47:7e:20:57:3e:f8:da:a9:73:32:37:a9:67:7f:
                    a9:34:4b:5f:6b:24:a4:4b:3b:39:ad:af:c0:f2:9c:
                    ab:c6:ea:4c:60:dd:d4:c2:9f:98:52:1a:00:6d:02:
                    58:11:6f:c0:e5:40:17:b4:31:72:5e:66:24:06:1c:
                    cc:01:ca:7e:bc:fa:40:1c:1f:ec:7d:f4:54:a6:4b:
                    6b:a1
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:51:BF:5E:48:55:C7:01:CD:B7:F9:0B:9D:D5:64:93:C8:E8:A4:B3:B2

            Authority Information Access: 
                OCSP - URI:http://ipa-ca.sub.berettadomaine.fr/ca/ocsp

            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Non Repudiation, Key Encipherment, Data Encipherment
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
            X509v3 CRL Distribution Points: 

                Full Name:
                  URI:http://ipa-ca.sub.berettadomaine.fr/ipa/crl/MasterCRL.bin
                CRL Issuer:
                  DirName: O = ipaca, CN = Certificate Authority

            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                4D:63:91:0C:9C:41:F1:6C:39:2D:E5:4D:82:3D:77:82:A7:4B:E8:A6
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:server.berettadomaine.fr, othername:<unsupported>, othername:<unsupported>
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         0b:9c:e9:0c:38:a9:5f:f6:3f:1e:9b:36:d7:83:79:c1:bc:ec:
         89:a2:da:94:ee:5e:fc:b0:a2:76:27:58:80:de:59:77:41:07:
         67:2d:6e:7e:6b:06:21:3f:69:af:26:7b:30:8d:21:41:4e:f4:
         32:7d:9c:46:e4:d1:d4:0d:df:3c:12:4e:f9:08:eb:ae:ff:8d:
         37:cf:00:60:ab:88:cd:22:f0:5c:e1:1e:30:0d:1e:67:07:cb:
         7b:07:15:3d:0e:67:b3:9a:4e:46:95:ee:62:22:6e:7a:57:39:
         54:05:99:0c:fb:cd:3f:26:08:17:fc:8b:5b:5d:15:04:f8:5c:
         72:68:05:e9:80:55:f7:c4:a4:11:d5:a1:4d:58:48:0f:c2:fb:
         43:85:42:da:e6:47:05:39:10:d7:81:ac:c0:bb:d3:f9:60:14:
         56:e5:94:ae:38:d7:3f:4b:6d:34:78:e3:68:67:6d:22:87:89:
         b3:5e:1e:84:45:63:43:57:9b:4e:87:0f:c9:10:0c:d8:7b:d0:
         4b:76:41:2c:d9:e5:57:4e:ee:c9:a4:cf:f1:bd:e6:aa:38:2b:
         39:24:3e:34:47:c1:c3:be:c7:e7:16:91:34:44:9e:62:24:06:
         1e:d2:38:f6:c2:7f:84:62:39:c4:fc:69:81:40:8d:e1:bb:9b:
         c1:e0:e6:39
```

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 1 (0x1)
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: O=BERETTADOMAINE.FR, CN=Certificate Authority
        Validity
            Not Before: Dec 21 05:51:00 2019 GMT
            Not After : Dec 21 05:51:00 2039 GMT
        Subject: O=BERETTADOMAINE.FR, CN=Certificate Authority
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:cc:11:0a:63:99:49:7c:a5:c1:c7:94:ad:81:48:
                    39:64:f6:a8:f9:7e:e7:6f:c0:1a:fd:51:15:0b:d1:
                    5b:36:d5:d5:c0:81:a4:da:8c:98:38:da:38:89:b1:
                    c4:f6:fc:a4:a1:b8:a8:c1:07:e9:b3:3e:92:09:16:
                    d5:77:1b:4b:87:4d:3f:93:ef:57:84:be:6d:79:16:
                    e7:b7:8f:ab:94:3d:ba:aa:f8:b8:e2:74:5f:e7:c5:
                    74:4e:32:75:26:b3:aa:18:2a:87:ad:90:e5:fe:4f:
                    54:65:33:52:a2:4a:6b:e0:77:6f:36:ad:c8:52:a3:
                    85:e4:fb:bc:25:07:b5:1a:0c:23:2a:87:62:59:4e:
                    b2:1c:5a:20:04:b0:44:73:b6:a5:14:5d:83:e3:9c:
                    43:7d:16:e4:28:07:8e:c1:78:b7:de:b2:7d:43:6c:
                    46:b6:7d:0f:26:d6:83:00:3e:ca:6f:7b:75:08:e7:
                    3c:90:8b:42:4b:3a:68:e5:88:2f:36:0a:58:53:29:
                    63:a3:eb:49:4e:42:c2:74:d6:e3:31:53:20:60:c5:
                    4c:3b:81:48:d7:4a:f4:12:ad:9b:e5:8e:78:ea:1d:
                    84:14:50:63:19:6c:f3:37:b1:43:6a:d7:1a:c4:c6:
                    be:80:dc:19:df:14:8d:92:5a:4f:75:4e:b7:4a:19:
                    ce:4d
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:52:5F:DD:DA:9B:F1:C3:7F:1D:93:FA:64:18:93:87:0F:44:14:76:18

            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Non Repudiation, Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                52:5F:DD:DA:9B:F1:C3:7F:1D:93:FA:64:18:93:87:0F:44:14:76:18
            Authority Information Access: 
                OCSP - URI:http://ipa-ca.berettadomaine.fr/ca/ocsp

    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         16:ac:8c:04:12:be:d0:1d:f1:bc:f0:aa:6d:3d:6c:5e:06:2f:
         4f:ca:4e:a9:ab:88:25:58:69:c5:83:85:78:3e:4a:42:c2:17:
         2c:4b:3a:8b:1a:94:94:72:f6:1c:7e:8e:2c:d3:ad:db:27:64:
         56:b8:e6:85:92:b2:71:d0:2f:56:7f:ca:08:48:e0:64:31:8c:
         9a:04:47:c1:78:56:76:57:44:2e:ca:91:b4:9d:30:a8:73:5e:
         55:9a:12:08:ff:85:46:dd:74:fc:27:f2:92:34:24:27:06:c7:
         5a:24:a0:cf:ce:ce:22:0e:42:6c:3e:ca:11:fc:27:01:6e:dd:
         bc:d3:0c:46:da:c3:af:47:87:15:a2:fe:86:fe:53:5e:d2:3c:
         ad:c0:60:fc:c6:64:74:f7:d8:ee:16:75:cb:91:68:e0:02:2f:
         71:82:27:69:3e:3c:cc:3f:19:88:60:f8:dd:8c:6c:20:37:ef:
         52:f4:b2:78:57:7e:f7:6a:c3:6a:6f:7e:f1:a3:b9:0f:f3:89:
         f8:7e:2a:e3:b7:af:0e:b3:82:b6:84:b9:64:60:df:16:68:31:
         14:f3:da:36:8a:e5:e3:c9:b0:66:14:e4:34:e7:eb:eb:8a:98:
         6e:dc:fd:fb:f8:f9:2c:8d:26:6e:dd:4d:38:5a:d5:89:1b:cb:
         4d:d5:14:44
```

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 11 (0xb)
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: O=BERETTADOMAINE.FR, CN=Certificate Authority
        Validity
            Not Before: Dec 25 12:12:51 2019 GMT
            Not After : Dec 25 12:12:51 2021 GMT
        Subject: O=DTI, CN=SUB.BERETTADOMAINE.FR
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:cc:55:5a:24:f3:e8:de:a4:93:ec:3e:a9:57:15:
                    da:b5:f8:1c:6d:84:38:94:53:e1:ca:54:15:8c:5f:
                    00:43:8e:bb:bc:a6:1f:55:dd:73:33:d9:f9:e6:cc:
                    ee:6c:af:58:12:0d:88:3b:44:d2:d9:7b:d0:98:13:
                    0d:0e:be:73:9e:0d:3b:3c:16:f4:28:e1:80:15:ec:
                    b7:2f:69:4e:19:a9:a2:9e:49:e5:ee:14:0d:82:01:
                    17:e4:72:42:41:da:86:a1:44:34:b8:2d:b4:64:e4:
                    ce:ed:69:21:f8:8b:82:ff:8e:a4:a7:2b:0f:92:91:
                    0b:11:95:03:0e:5f:69:7b:42:67:0b:7b:47:ed:56:
                    92:94:64:b2:fe:d1:ff:38:16:f0:a1:11:d1:8b:39:
                    33:2e:9f:72:24:f5:ba:a7:8f:96:6c:7b:c0:d1:df:
                    f3:ab:bb:38:10:a1:46:c9:8b:32:ef:f9:76:07:83:
                    00:ee:a5:7f:48:1f:c8:2b:21:36:18:74:be:04:fa:
                    9c:c7:ee:d8:4a:91:84:ea:e3:8b:b0:25:d4:1f:c5:
                    34:c2:e0:13:10:ad:ce:7a:d4:f2:c5:91:89:a5:61:
                    1c:32:39:cc:d0:fa:b5:66:f6:16:d0:3d:3f:71:6f:
                    84:98:50:a1:e1:e7:dc:b0:67:2d:5f:c6:da:76:75:
                    eb:cb
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:52:5F:DD:DA:9B:F1:C3:7F:1D:93:FA:64:18:93:87:0F:44:14:76:18

            Authority Information Access: 
                OCSP - URI:http://ipa-ca.berettadomaine.fr/ca/ocsp

            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Non Repudiation, Key Encipherment, Data Encipherment, Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
            X509v3 CRL Distribution Points: 

                Full Name:
                  URI:http://ipa-ca.berettadomaine.fr/ipa/crl/MasterCRL.bin
                CRL Issuer:
                  DirName: O = ipaca, CN = Certificate Authority

            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                51:BF:5E:48:55:C7:01:CD:B7:F9:0B:9D:D5:64:93:C8:E8:A4:B3:B2
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE, pathlen:0
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         32:a7:24:53:1b:c7:07:8e:e8:b9:13:76:f9:50:53:f9:94:67:
         8d:5a:42:ed:e9:93:0e:62:af:17:c5:51:cc:96:00:f1:5e:81:
         c1:44:d5:60:40:61:76:33:35:78:dc:23:f1:17:94:00:1f:2a:
         32:2d:b4:ad:51:73:01:66:1a:bf:35:b6:35:bf:ab:63:ca:fc:
         d5:e5:2c:86:ce:1a:ac:20:db:44:6d:ef:53:3a:b2:a4:56:fb:
         d9:13:5a:2d:d9:10:78:d2:59:d7:92:91:65:12:c0:8d:74:a2:
         c3:3d:71:21:e1:9d:97:11:50:c2:ef:bb:08:1a:aa:16:d6:5a:
         ec:5d:cb:9c:72:db:ba:4d:3b:3f:66:76:57:bc:88:83:24:b4:
         7a:f0:0d:c6:10:ff:1d:d2:1d:fd:ca:4c:9c:cf:5a:bb:35:11:
         43:24:16:66:96:e5:e6:7a:67:7d:8e:f2:7d:a7:65:03:27:1b:
         2c:02:6a:f7:ae:a0:27:c7:de:b6:d9:3c:3b:5d:6e:38:4e:93:
         df:c0:e6:f3:75:07:7d:f1:0c:a3:4a:94:53:e5:c6:bb:7f:32:
         40:fd:61:5e:2f:bf:85:1c:e1:d3:1f:20:92:4d:f6:cc:5f:5e:
         7c:71:2d:42:7d:2f:a1:2c:cb:0b:25:aa:b8:c0:00:65:f3:45:
         56:86:68:46
```

So, root ca is not trusted but, however, I put the option "-CAfile root_ca.crt...

Do you know where is my fault, how can I check all the chain please?

Thank you very much.

Comment: While you claim what in the various files is in theory it is unknown what is in these files in reality. It is also unknown who signed the OCSP response, which might be done by a different sub-CA. Thus in order to reproduce what you are doing and to be able to help you, you would not to provide the actual contents of all these files.

Comment: Thank you Steffen. I edited my post.

Comment: The text only representation of the certificates is not sufficient to reproduce, the actual certificate (PEM) are needed.

Comment: I think it will be difficult to reproduce for you because you need to connect to the certificate authority and it's on private network, not accessible from internet. I thought it was possible to help with what i wrote. I can give more details.

Comment: It is impossible to say based on this which certificate was used to sign the OCSP response(s). Note that it might be a different subCA as for the certificate itself, i.e. one you don't have in your chain file.

Comment: I have only one subCA. I am going to try to understand. I thank you Steffen for your time.